# Difference between SOAP and REST

Tags: performance, rest, security, soap

what's the advantages and disadvantages of SOAP ?
what's the advantages and disadvantages of REST ?

In each cases you should use rest or soap ?

impact of the choice in Non functional requirements ( NRFS )  for exemple security , performance , scalability ....

Comment: This has been really well documented online. I don't think this question even needs an answer - instead it needs a Google search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an alternative way that could help: REST services. REST (REpresentational State Transfer) isn't a framework or toolkit but architectural style or approach trying to simplify the life in web services

https://blogs.oracle.com/milan/entry/web_services_rest_vs_soap

Answer (score 0):

SOAP is a protocol while REST is an interaction scheme.

Actually SOAP is a way of REST with a very low maturity model level of 0 (see http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html).

Answering all your other questions comprehensively would by far exceed the scope of this platform.